# How do the `require`s in React's repo work?

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking into extending a react addon and looking through the require statements it looks like a lot of them are requiring modules that don't exist. How does that work?

If I'm looking to make extend ReactTransitionGroup, that has require('ReactTransitionChildMapping');, but `ReactTransitionChildMapping` isn't a module, what should I do?

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/addons/transitions/ReactTransitionGroup.js

You can see it requiring a bunch of things that aren't npm modules.

Comment: I just stumbled across a [video with Ben Alpert talking about this](https://youtu.be/wUpPsEcGsg8?t=672).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The React repo (and presumably other systems at Facebook) use a custom `require` resolution solution based around the `@providesModule` annotation in various files. These get compiled down into standard CommonJS modules via a build step. [Check out `ReactTransitionChildMapping.js`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/6f5e619fae3901bbe6684cd489ad04d1bec3e39c/src/addons/transitions/ReactTransitionChildMapping.js#L9) and you'll see the following comment, as part of a block comment:

```
@providesModule ReactTransitionChildMapping
```